# Shared data and unique data among multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java which code is shared between multiple threads and which code is being copied to be used for one particular thread ?

Too be more precise if one would consider the following fragment

```
public void foo () {

    int a = 0;

    a++;
}
```

being executed by multiple threads concurrently will each thread hold its own copy of the variable `a`or is it shared between the threads?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `a` is a local variable. That means each invocation of `foo` gets its own separate variable - whether that's in multiple threads or even recursively within the same thread.

Note that this isn't about sharing *code* - it's about sharing *data*. The same code will be running (well, probably) in all threads, but each invocation will work with a separate set of local variables.

Comment: Jon, Thank you very much. Your help is alway much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Very good question.

This is pretty important to understand while using threads in general.

In your case, since a is declared inside the function foo, it is local to threads. So, all threads should have their own copy of a variable.

Suppose, a is declared outside of this function, then it would be global and you may have to use Lock to make sure a is updated by every single thread.